# MySQL: Finding the missing values from tables

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables:

1. **checkin_out** consists of two fields: **emp_code**, **checked_date**
2. **temp_days** consists of two fields: **id**, **date_value**

Table **checkin_out** has following data:

```
emp_code | checked_date
-----------------------
001        2012-11-01
001        2012-11-02
001        2012-11-03
002        2012-11-01
003        2012-11-01
003        2012-11-02
```

While table **temp_days** has following data:

```
id  | date_value
-----------------
1     2012-11-01
2     2012-11-02
3     2012-11-03
4     2012-11-04
5     2012-11-05
```

From the above tables, I need to show the missing dates in the table **temp_days**; I need to query to get a result as follow:

```
emp_code  |  date_value
-----------------------
001          2012-11-04
001          2012-11-05
002          2012-11-02
002          2012-11-03
002          2012-11-04
002          2012-11-05
003          2012-11-03
003          2012-11-04
003          2012-11-05
```

If anyone could help, please! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works for a more complex data set with multiple emp_codes.

```
SELECT  alldays.emp_code, alldays.date_value
FROM    (
          SELECT date_value, emp_code
          FROM temp_days
          CROSS JOIN checkin_out
          GROUP BY date_value, emp_code
        ) alldays
        LEFT JOIN checkin_out C
            ON alldays.date_value = C.checked_date
            AND alldays.emp_code = C.emp_code
WHERE   C.emp_code IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, let me try it first.

Comment: You're like a genius in SQL. It works perfectly for more complex data with multiple emp_codes. Thank you very much indeed for the brilliant solution. I'd spent my whole day looking for the right solution, only this one works for me.

Comment: No problem - CROSS JOIN is ideal for this kind of query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  c.emp_code, a.date_value
FROM    temp_days a
        LEFT JOIN checkin_out b
            ON a.date_value = b.checked_date
        CROSS JOIN 
        (
            SELECT emp_code
            FROM checkin_out
            GROUP BY emp_code
        ) c
WHERE   b.emp_code IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61c06/4)

Comment: This'll work for the simple example - but the CROSS JOIN is not right as there's nothing joining it to "those days which are not present for a given emp_code".

Comment: @WillA I don't really get what you mean on the point that said "CROSS JOIN is not right as there's nothing joining it to <<those days which as not present for a given emp_code>>". It would be great if you could raise any example that make the CROSS JOIN not right as you mentioned above. Thanks

Comment: Try adding {emp_code = 002, checked_date = 2012-11-01} to your checkin_out table, then run the query.

Comment: @Kuya-John I have tested with my real data by applying your solution and I'm wondering why it took up to __9.2880 sec__ to get result from my localhost server with 99 rows found.

Comment: @WillA Yes, you're right about it. I didn't realize until I tested and looked thru all employees in my real data and see that no matter what I still get the same result for all employees. I could see your point here now. Thanks a lot. And It seems that the this solution only works for a single employee.